# Hyperlink in outlook which will open new mail with image embedded in body

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, outlook

Outlook : 2013

I need to send mail to client with hyperlink in the body tag.As soon as client clicks on the hyperlink, new mail should be opened with some auto filled details like  subject,to address and image in the body (most important thing).

simple use case:  sending birthday mailers . as soon as we click on hyperlink, new mail should be opened with toaddress, subject and image in the body auto present so that we can just click the send button.

Can you please let me know how to achieve this ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto

Comment: @soorapadman : Thanks ! But this will not solve my problem since i want it sent as a part of e-mail

Answer (score 0):

mailto only handles plan text body and subject. No HTML or attachments.

You can create an EML file (which is text) and make the user open it instead - Outlook will be happy to display the message with all its attachments and HTML body. To make sure Outlook displays the message in the unsent state, set the `X-Unsent` MIME header to 1.

Comment: hello. X-unsent makes inline images shown as attachments in 'compose' time. is it possible to make them visible in wysiwyg editor of outlook?

Comment: What are the img tags in your HTML?